# How to make a comparison of EXISTING file id in a spreadsheet with the NEW file id from google drive folder using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I was given a requirement from the business side to list out all the selected files from a selected folder into a google sheet.

User might list out/load the files more than one time from the google folder into google sheet. Therefore, I am trying to make a comparison of the **existing file id** (in the google sheet) with the **new file id**. This comparison of file id's will occur when user try to click a function(example: "Update List")

So if there is any new files been uploaded into the google drive folder, only new uploaded file needs to be listed inside the list in google sheet with other old files.

Here is a sample for clearer understanding:

[image]

The sample above shows a few list of files listed in google sheet when the user runs the script for the **FIRST TIME**

[image]

In this above example sample, after user click on a function "Update List", file id comparison take place and **only new uploaded file need to displayed**. In addition, i would like to have a column which act as a **marker** to notify the user the **old file and new file**.

Since i manage to list down the selected files in the google sheet.

Here is the code of me trying to make a comparison between **existing file id** and **new id** in a separate script file.

```
function getChildFiles(parentName, parent) {

var fileIter = parent.searchFiles("title contains'completed'and title contains 'Verification Visit Direct Suppliers'and mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'"); 

var folderId = parent.getId();
var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

while (childFolders.hasNext()) { // Iterate through folders in folder
 var childFolder = childFolders.next();
 var childFolderName = childFolder.getName();
 getChildFiles(
   parentName + ' |--> ' + childFolderName,
   childFolder
  );   
 }

while (fileIter.hasNext()) { // Iterate through files in folder

  var file = fileIter.next();
  var fileName = file.getName();
  var fileID = file.getId();

  var NEWid = fileID;
  
  UpdateList(NEWid,fileName,fileID );
   }} 

function UpdateList (NEWid,fileName,fileID){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var r= 2;

for (r=2; r < sheet.getLastRow(); r++){
 var oldID = sheet.getRange(r,1).getValues(); 

 if(oldID != NEWid){
 sheet.getRange(r,1).setValue(fileID);
 sheet.getRange(r,2).setValue(fileName);
   }}
 }
```

But i could not able to display it properly after i tried uploading some new files.

My goal is to:

1. Able to compare the **existing file id** with **new file id**
2. List only new uploaded files in the list when user click on "Update List" function while **keeping the old list**.
3. Able to show **marker** in the "Status" column to differentiate between old file and new file

**AFTER IMPLEMENTING THE CODE**

I am manage to add the new list of files but however the status **still remains as "OLD FILE"**. How can i change it to convert it into **"NEW FILE"**.

Comment: Unfortunately the logic is incorrect, your code will write each file ID to each row of the table if it does not match the ID. You'd probably end up with the last file ID repeated all over the sheet. You would want to list all IDs from drive and from sheet in separate arrays, compare each element, and list ID's which exist only in drive array and not in sheet array.

Comment: Do you ever try to save you code before submitting as an example? This code is giving syntax error upon attempting to save.  What is this: `getChildFiles(
   parentName + ' |--> ' + childFolderName,
   childFolder
  );   
 }` Have you ever even read [mcve] if not please do and provide one.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for the reply and the correction. I guess i have edited `var fileIter = parent.searchFiles("title contains 'completed' and title contains 'Verification Visit Direct Suppliers' and mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' "); `. Sorry for the syntax error that i have caused maybe it happened when i was trying to copy and paste the code in here.

Comment: @Cooper For this line, `getChildFiles( parentName + ' |--> ' + childFolderName, childFolder );` I was been helped to implement this line of code, so that the list able to populate in the google sheet. If i try to remove this line, i couldn't able to  populate the list of files.

Comment: @CarlosM thanks for replying, i roughly get the idea. However, i would like to know whether will this idea work efficiently for data comparing more than 100 ids'??

Comment: Yes, it would be much faster than accessing google API's such as ``SpreadsheetApp`` per file.

Answer (score 0):

### A more efficient method can be like this:

1. Iterate through all the files and push them into a temporary array `newFileArr`. I'll just assume you have all the files you need in `fileIter`:

```
var newFileArr = [];

while (fileIter.hasNext()) {
  var file = fileIter.next();
  var fileName = file.getName();
  var fileID = file.getId();
  newFileArr.push([fileID, fileName]);
}
```

2. Prepare your spreadsheet data:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var oldIDArr = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1).getValues();
```

3. Loop to compare:

```
  // old data column
  var marker = new Array(oldIDArr.length).fill(['OLD FILE']);

  var addedFiles = [];

  // compare old files with new files
  for (i = 0; i < newFileArr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < oldIDArr.length; j++) {
      if (newFileArr[i][0] == oldIDArr[j][0]) {
        break;
      }
    }
    // this is for new file
    if (j == oldIDArr.length) {
      addedFiles.push(newFileArr[i]);
      marker.push(['NEW FILE']);
    }
  }
```

4. Add the new entries to the spreadsheet:

```
  if (addedFiles.length > 0) {
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(lr+1,1,addedFiles.length,2);
    newRange.setValues(addedFiles);
  }
  var markerRange = sheet.getRange(2,9,marker.length);
  markerRange.setValues(marker);
```

This is what it looks like with sample data:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the guideline, i have tried implementing the code above. However the new uploaded file's marker is still showing as the "OLD FILE" status. Where can i make the changes in the code?

Comment: It would be best if you share a sample spreadsheet with sample data that shows the behavior you are describing.

Comment: can i know how can i share the sample because i couldn't share image in the comment section? Or should i re-edit my question and place the sample in there?

Comment: edit your question to include a **link** to the spreadsheet, not an image.

Comment: And you're probably running the script multiple times without an update to the Drive. The new files would be remarked as old files in subsequent runs.

Comment: how can i avoid the script from running multiple times? Because i run the script only once...it appeared as new file in the beginning and after that changes into old file but i run the script only once

Comment: You would have to check your function executions in the code. Unfortunately I can only test with dummy data as I don't have real file ID's.

Comment: i notice that when we try to get range for the `oldIDArr`, it includes the **New File ID** as well as an OLD ID after it been added into the list. For example, if **2 new files** are been added today, when i run the script it will get the 1st new file, and when it tries to get the 2nd new file, the 1st file became an old file. End up both file become old file at the end.

What if i create a spreadsheet with code in it and i give you the access to the spreadsheet? as well as the folder for you to test/try data? Maybe you can have a look on it?